# Email address or username used to login in wordpress

Tags: login

How can i allow users to login to my wordpress site using both email id and username? Currently it is allowing only username.

Comment: Sorry, plugin/theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations) here. Try the [WordPress group on Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/101504763068635549461) or [wordpress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of WordPress 4.5, logging in with the email address instead of username has been added to core functionality.  It was introduced in [ticket 9568](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9568).

If you are running a version of WordPress older than 4.5, the following small small plugin will work. If you don't (or can't) use a plugin, this should - in theory - as well work from within your `functions.php` file. Just leave the plugin comment header out.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#90328) Login with E-Mail address */
function login_with_email_address( &$username ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
    if ( !empty( $user->user_login ) )
        $username = $user->user_login;
    return $username;
}
add_action( 'wp_authenticate','login_with_email_address' );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited your question as this is plugin territory and shouldn't be part of a theme. I left your statement in, but offered it as plugin as well.